# Compose monadic and pure function

Tags: haskell

Let's find files that not exist in the current directory:

```
filterM (\f -> return . not =<< doesFileExist f) files
```

And now I want to do it better with point notation:

```
filterM (liftM not . doesFileExist) files
```

Are there another approaches to do this? For example, later works not so good for composition of pure functions, need braces:

```
filterM (liftM (isExtensionPNG . not) . doesFileExist) files
```

Comment: I don't think the last example does what you intended. For that to typecheck, `isExtensionPNG` would have to have the type `Bool -> Bool`, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Agree with @hammar, you probably wanna use `not . isExtensionPNG`

Comment: What you call “point notation” is usually called *“point-free style”* (or, more disparagingly, “pointless style”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an infix operator to make it nicer to write:

```
infixr 9 .: -- same as .

(.:) :: Monad m => (b -> c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
f .: g = liftM f . g


filterM (isExtensionPNG .: not .: doesFileExist) files
```

Answer (score 2):

Since every monad is a functor with `liftM` as `fmap`, you can use the fact that `fmap` distributes over function composition.

```
fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g
```

You can therefore write

```
filterM (liftM isExtensionPNG . liftM not . doesFileExist) files
```

Though to be honest, I prefer your original version.